# Type Error: unable to get value of the property

Tags: java, javascript, tomcat, gwt, extjs

I am working on a java and gwt based application. I am getting the follwowing error when i am trying to view the pages in the application. I have searched over internet but i could not get the answer which could help me to understand the issue and fix it

> (TypeError): Unable to get value of the property 'cf': object is null or undefined description: Unable to get value of the property 'cf': object is null or undefined number: -2146823281

I have checked both the tomcat and Catalina logs and i could not find any error which could help me in resolving this issue. Can someone please help in fixing the issue.

I have checked searched for the complete application and i could see a function with name cf which is a gwt related html file.
Below is the function.

```
function cf(b,c){
   var d;
   yb();
   if(!$){
     return
   }
   b.e||ef(b);
   if(b.b!=c){
      if(c.xc){
          b.b = c;
          b.c = b.b.Xd();
          d = (ah(), Ui(b.c,r3b));
          Yh(Dh(d), false);
          Dh(d).n.appendChild(b.d.n);
          b.d.ld(true);
          gf(b,b.b)
      }
   }
}
```

Can someone help me in if anyone has faced the same kind of issue and how this can be resolved

Comment: Do proper Formatting of your question

Comment: minified code is difficult to check...

Comment: You should try running it in SuperDev mode (http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html). If you don't, the Java code you write will be compiled into javascript where all your original function and variables names are gone. If you use superdev mode the javascript code will reflect your original names. That said, what is most likely wrong is that something in your code is null.

Comment: Hi- I am facing the similar situation. Did you able to figure it out?